# Why is Chrome placing two global objects on the prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, v8, webidl

**Background**

By reading the [Web IDL spec](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/) section that relates to [creating new *platform objects*](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#internally-create-a-new-object-implementing-the-interface), we know that when the global object is created its [[prototype]] is set to the global *interface object*'s *instance prototype object* (which was created previously, when the [*interface object* was created](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#create-an-interface-object)).

By looking at the section describing how [*interface prototype objects* are created](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-prototype-object), we see that the global object's [[prototype]] gets its [[prototype]] set to the *named properties object*.

That object, in turn, gets [[prototype]] linked to whatever the global interface inherited from.

As seen, the prototype chain defined for the global object by the IDL and HTML specs, is as follows:

```
window -> Window.prototype -> WindowProperties (the *named properties object*) -> EventTarget.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
```

**Question**

Firefox creates that exact prototype chain, but Chrome seems to add one extra copy of the global object to the chain. If you `console.dir(window)` and look at the console in Chrome, it shows:

```
window -> window -> Window.prototype -> WindowProperties (the *named properties object*) -> EventTarget.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
```

Interestingly, `console.dir(Object.getPrototypeOf(window))` in Chrome will indeed log *Window.prototype*, so the oddity is that first "global object copy" added to the start of the chain.

Why does Chrome do that, and can that behavior be found in any spec?

Comment: A longer chain on this and similar topics can be seen here (for those interested): https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250856/room-for-magnus-and-bergi-web-idl

Comment: Does it have any impact on the results? If not, then it's allowed by the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

I'm pretty sure this is just an internal implementation detail (`window` is split into two objects under the hood, for complicated reasons) that the `console.dir` implementation isn't hiding correctly. Filed [crbug.com/1405301](https://crbug.com/1405301).

Rest assured that the prototype chain that regular JavaScript code can observe is as it should be, with no unexpected copies of anything. You can easily check this with `window.__proto__ === Window.prototype`, which returns `true` as it should.

Comment: Thank you. In case you know the answer, here is another question I just posted related to how browsers create the global window object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75026200/how-can-the-global-window-object-be-created-before-there-is-a-realm-in-existance

Comment: Could you go into a bit of detail on those "complicated reasons", please?

Comment: @Bergi: it's the actual global object and its proxy, which the spec calls `WindowProxy`. They appear as one object to JS code, but are actually two, and IIRC that becomes observable in certain situations around navigation. (I'm not an expert on that stuff, sorry.) V8 implements this as the real global object being the proxy's prototype, which makes many things "just work" but does require a bit of special-casing here and there.

Comment: Thanks @jmrk. In case interested, we are debating an aspect of how the WindowProxy object works under the hood, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75033793/what-is-the-purpose-of-passing-windowproxy-as-the-global-this-value/75039463#75039463