# How can the global window object be created before there is a realm in existance?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, specifications, webidl

**Background**

When a browser opens a new window or tab, a new *browsing context* is created.

As we can see from the HTML spec, the [operation that creates a new browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/document-sequences.html#creating-a-new-browsing-context) calls [another operation that creates a new realm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#creating-a-new-javascript-realm), which in turn calls the operation [InitializeHostDefinedRealm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-initializehostdefinedrealm) defined in the ECMAScript spec.

The HTML spec operation that creates the browsing context states that when a new realm is created it should be done with a new `Window` object as the *global object*, and a `WindowProxy` object as the global **this** value.

Within [InitializeHostDefinedRealm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-initializehostdefinedrealm), we see that a new realm is created in step 1. In step 7, the *global object* is created in a host-defined manner.

If we take a look at the Web IDL spec, we can see how [*platform objects* (instances of *interface objects*) are created](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#internally-create-a-new-object-implementing-the-interface).

For it to be possible for a *platform object* (like the *global object* `window`) to be created, the corresponding *interface object* (which is a *function object*) must have been created previously via the [operation for creating interface objects](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#create-an-interface-object). This is because the latter operation [creates the *interface prototype object*](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#create-an-interface-prototype-object) for the interface.

Taking it back to the *global object*, creating the *interface object* `Window` will create `Window.prototype`, which will be used when the *platform object* `window` (an instance of *interface object* `Window`) is created.

Lastly, we also know from the [operation that creates *platform objects*](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#internally-create-a-new-object-implementing-the-interface) that the operation requires `realm.[[GlobalObject]]` to be present, for instance to check if an interface member is *Exposed* on a realm: [Create platform object (see step 10.1)](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#internally-create-a-new-object-implementing-the-interface) > [Add Regular operations that are exposed on `Window` (see step 1.1)](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#define-the-operations)  > [**exposed** definition](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-exposed)

**Questions**

1. In [InitializeHostDefinedRealm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-initializehostdefinedrealm), `realm.[[GlobalObject]]` is not set until *after* the host has created the new `Window` object (step 9 vs step 7). `realm.[[GlobalObject]]` cannot be set without a *global object* present, and the *global object* `window` cannot be created without `realm.[[GlobalObject]]` present. How is this apparent deadlock solved?
2. Step 9 of the [operation that creates a browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/document-sequences.html#creating-a-new-browsing-context) states that a new `Window` object should be created as the *global object*, without any further details on how that is accomplished. Does it imply that the browser *first* creates the `Window` *interface object* and then the corresponding `window` *platform object*?

Comment: You seem to be conflating the WebIDL interfaces, that are accessible only internally by the browser/specs and the exposed interface objects, which are accessible from JS. These aren't the same. Many interfaces aren't exposed anywhere (e.g TypedArray, or DOMMatrixInit etc.). When the specs ask to create a Window object they don't ask to create a JS object, but an instance of the WebIDL interface.

Comment: @Kaiido Agreed, but when the HTML spec does "*Perform [InitializeHostDefinedRealm()](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-initializehostdefinedrealm) with the provided customizations for creating the global object and the global this binding.*", then those customisations would need to be the exposed JS objects, no? Or does this happen implicitly via the ECMAScript WebIDL binding?

Comment: @Bergi yes I think that when ES says "let global be such an object created in a host-defined manner." there is everything needed to produce that JS object through WebIDL.

Comment: @Kaiido The Web IDL spec had a whole section on how interfaces translate to ECMAScript objects. It tells us the operations for creating *interface objects* and *platform objects*, both ECMAScript objects . If we are thinking about a browser's use of the spec to create the global object accessible in a JavaScript script, then surely *InitializeHostDefinedRealm*'s step 7 is asking the host to create an ECMAScript object out of the Window object, no? The Web IDL spec shows how that's done, and it isn't possible without a `realm.[[GlobalObject]]` already present. What am I missing?

Comment: We have a chat here, if helpful to debate a bit: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250856/room-for-magnus-and-bergi-web-idl

Comment: @Kaiido 
The chain of operations showing the `realm.[[GlobalObject]]` requirement when creating a *platform object*: https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#internally-create-a-new-object-implementing-the-interface (e.g. step 10.1) > https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#define-the-operations (step 1.1) > https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-exposed (**exposed** definition)

Comment: ... You're right there is something fishy in here. I'm starting to doubt if we really call WebIDL's *new* here though. ES apparently has [its own way of creating the global object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-global-object). Maybe there is some allowed magic around here. I'll poke around on WHATWG's chat to try to get the attention of someone that might be more familiar.

Comment: @Domenic answered on whatwg's matrix: *It's essentially atomic. This is what is intended by https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/document-sequences.html#creating-a-new-browsing-context step 9 being a single step instead of something like "1. create the Window; 2. create the realm and supply the Window to it."* It's a bit late for me right now to do the follow up, and I hope he'll chime in here, but to me that kinda sounds like the "magic" supposition was close.